# PHP "error Array sizes are inconsistent" al ordenar arreglo multidimensional de objetos

Tags: php, array

estoy intentando ordenar un arreglo multidimensional de objetos mediante el siguiente código:

```
      $col  = 'payment_date';
      $sort = array();
      foreach ($result as $res) 
        foreach ($res as $i => $doc) 
            $sort[$i] = $doc->payment_date;
    
      
      $sorted_db = array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $result);
      
      var_dump($result);
```

El var_dump del arreglo de objetos $result es el siguiente:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(ExpensesData)#12 (35) { ["description"]=> string(14) "Movimeinto 232" ["amount"]=> string(5) "10000" ["upload_receipt"]=> string(0) "" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["category_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipo"]=> string(7) "Tarjeta" ["entidad"]=> string(2) "23" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2022-03-03 14:32:43" ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2022-03-03" ["fecha_vence"]=> string(10) "2022-03-03" ["pagado"]=> string(1) "1" ["document_number"]=> string(5) "1-232" ["documento"]=> string(0) "" ["pago"]=> string(0) "" ["pagado_con"]=> string(8) "efectivo" ["empresa"]=> string(1) "2" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" ["payment_date"]=> string(10) "2021-12-31" ["payment_specific_date"]=> string(10) "2022-03-03" ["deuda_id"]=> NULL ["movimiento"]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(3) "272" ["neto"]=> string(1) "0" ["pagoconvalor"]=> string(2) "23" ["auditado"]=> string(1) "0" ["pago_multiple"]=> NULL ["gravado_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["exento_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["iva_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto1_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto2_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto3_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto4_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["bienes_uso"]=> string(1) "0" ["tipo_doc"]=> string(6) "Egreso" } } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(IncomeData)#13 (32) { ["description"]=> string(14) "Movimeinto 232" ["amount"]=> string(5) "10000" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["category_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["tipo"]=> string(5) "Banco" ["entidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2022-03-03 14:32:43" ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2022-03-03" ["pagado"]=> string(1) "1" ["document_number"]=> string(5) "1-232" ["documento"]=> string(0) "" ["fecha_vence"]=> string(10) "2022-03-03" ["pago"]=> string(0) "" ["pagado_con"]=> string(8) "efectivo" ["empresa"]=> string(1) "2" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" ["payment_date"]=> string(10) "2021-12-31" ["payment_specific_date"]=> string(10) "2022-03-03" ["movimiento"]=> string(3) "272" ["id"]=> string(3) "202" ["neto"]=> NULL ["pagoconvalor"]=> string(1) "1" ["deuda_id"]=> NULL ["pago_multiple"]=> NULL ["gravado_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["exento_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["iva_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto1_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto2_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto3_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["impuesto4_D_12_2"]=> string(1) "0" ["tipo_doc"]=> string(7) "Ingreso" } } }
```

quiero ordenar por la columna "payment_date" de manera ascendente, me sale el "error array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent".  El arreglo $result se obtiene de la siguiente forma:

```
$partner = ResultData::dynamicQuery($sWhere);
array_push($result, $partner);
$expenses = ExpensesData::dynamicQuery($sWhere);
array_push($result, $expenses);
$income = IncomeData::dynamicQuery($sWhere);
array_push($result, $income);
$debt = DebtsData::dynamicQuery($sWhere);
array_push($result, $debt);
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Al copiar y pegar tu código marca errores, `$result` tal como lo pusiste tiene algo mal.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato edite e incluí el var_dump del arreglo

Comment: Yo creo que en lugar del `var_dump` sería mejor que pusieras el contenido real, porque de otra forma tenemos que reescribir todo el arreglo manualmente

Comment: @HeytalePazguato cómo obtengo el contenido real?

Comment: Supongo que los datos los traes desde una BD, no seria mas conveniente ordenar desde la misma consulta esa columna que mencionas...

Comment: Pregunto: ¿por qué esos datos no vienen ordenados ya desde su origen? ¿el contexto en que se originan no depende de ti? ¿si no depende de ti, investigaste si hay forma de ordenar datos (muchas APIs y WS permiten ordenar los datos por determinados criterios).

Comment: lo datos se obtienen desde varias tablas distintas, hago un array push al arreglo $result, no he hecho un UNION con los datos, por limitaciones del sistema.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con *limitaciones del sistema*? Si el código que trae los datos depende de ti entonces ordena los datos ya en origen, no tiene sentido volver a manipularlos para ordenarlos, cuando puedes traerlos ordenados. Muestra el código con que obtienes tus datos y quizá podremos ayudarte a ordernarlos o incluso a optimizar tu código si es el caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano edité la pregunta

Comment: Con ese código poco podemos hacer, conviene que pongas cómo tienes definidas tus tablas y cómo se relacionan entre ellas. Lo propio aquí es que obtengas un solo conjunto de resultados, mediante una sola consulta, haciendo `JOIN` de las distintas tablas y ordenando los datos como los necesitas. Así habrás optimizado tu código (una sola consulta, no varias) y no tendrás que manipular los datos para ordenarlos a posteriori, porque los traerías ya ordenados.

Comment: y no es posible enfocarse en el arreglo? usando funciones PHP para ordenarlo

Comment: Te puedes enfocar en el arreglo si quieres, pero vas a tener un código no optimizado. Por ejemplo, estás ejecutando cuatro consultas para obtener un resultado, cuando puedes ejecutar una sola. El problema de esto es que, cada consulta tiene un coste y eso a la larga puede traerte problemas en contextos concurrentes o de muchos usuarios. El rendimiento se notará también a nivel de base de datos, porque, escribiendo una sola consulta, aprovecharás eventuales índices en las tablas, mientras que por separado, no sacarás provecho de ello y puede que también estés trayendo datos innecesarios.